# Make HTML element bigger than its sibling, limited by max/screen size

Tags: html, css, reactjs, layout, spacing

I'm trying to draw text with an underline below it, such that the underline spans to the sides **up to** 300 pixels. When there is no space for the whole 300 pixels, that amount should go down to make space for the text.
This is the correct behavior for a wide screen:
[image]

This is the correct behavior for a thin screen:
[image]

I've tried having empty divs on both sides of the 'hello' with `width: 300px`, but that doesn't work well:

```
<div style="width: fit-content; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
        <div style="width: 300px;"></div>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <div style="width: 300px;"></div>
    </div>
    <hr style="width: 100%;">
</div>
```

- If I set `width: fit-content` in the parent, I get the correct behavior on a wide screen, but on a thin screen the sides don't minimize themselves, and the divider clips out to outside the screen.
- If I don't set width in the parent, I get the correct behavior on a thin screen, but on a wide screen the divider fills the entire screen width, instead of only 300 px extra on each side.

Comment: why dont you just use flex-grow to occupy the remaining space equally instead of hardcotting the width? Alternativly even easier would be to put the text into a single element that span the entire width and use a bottom-border for that element. Cenetr the text with text-align.

Comment: I don't understand how you could extend the sides by X pixels using the methods you mentioned. Could you post a code example?

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure what you realy want but you can try this:
(add this in that div: max-width: 300px;width: 100%;  )

```
<div style="width: fit-content; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
        <div style="max-width: 300px;width: 100%;"></div>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <div style="max-width: 300px;width: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <hr style="width: 100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work at all, the sides will be extended by 0 pixels.